# Logitech Bluetooth audio receiver quality

Tags: audio, bluetooth

I bought a Logitech Bluetooth Audio receiver, and have run into a problem:

When playing audio, it contains short hisses/clicks on higher tones or vocal+heavy instrumental music (sound quality appears to be unclean).

I'm not sure what could be the reason, but this only happens when I play from certain devices.  My laptops (a Dell XPS Win7, and an Asus Eee Seashell Win7) and my phone (Samsung Player 5) both have the problem. However, when I tried using a Samsung S2 phone, the audio was crystal clear.

Seems that this could be something with Bluetooth transmitting device.

Has anyone encountered a similar problem?

Answer (score 1):

Bluetooth devices use different audio codecs, with only a lower quality audio codec mandatory. Your Galaxy S2 must support the higher quality codec, whereas your PC's and Galaxy Player 5 do not.

More info: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_profile#Advanced_Audio_Distribution_Profile_.28A2DP.29